# How to play a sound when the cursor hovers over an image?

Tags: javascript, audio, mouseover, twine

I'm on Twine using Harlowe 3.3.5.
I have an image:

```
<img src="coffee.png" id="coffee">
```

And I have a sound that I would like to play when the mouse hovers over the image. This is the JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var picture = document.getElementById('coffee');

  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = 'coffee.mp3';
  audio.preload = 'auto';

  picture.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

I tried both `mouseover` and `mouseenter`, but no sound comes out.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work? How else could I get the same result?